# What's the right way to install grails plugin on grails 2.3?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have to install grails twilio plugin on grails 2.3, plugin available here  https://github.com/Novadge/grails-twilio

Can someone help me to install this plugin on my grails 2.3 project?

Comment: What is the problem you're facing? Doesn't the documentation help? http://docs.grails.org/2.3.4/ref/Command%20Line/install-plugin.html

Comment: install-plugin not working . as its deprecated from 2.3 , i want to know how i can install without install-plugin command?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add this to your BuildConfig.groovy

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:twilio:0.1"
```

Documentation here: https://grails.org/plugin/twilio

Answer (score 1):

As given in the documentation you can install plugin by adding twillo configuration in the `config.groovy` file -

```
twilio {
    // Enter your host address
    host = 'https://api.twilio.com'
    apiID = 'enter your api Id'
    apiPass = 'enter your api password'
    smsUrl = '/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + apiID + '/Messages.json'
    number = ""
}
```

and other relevent dependent components under the `dependencies` in `BuildConfig.groovy` like -

```
     dependencies {
     .
     .
     //twilio plugin        
     compile "org.grails.plugins:twilio:0.1"

     compile(group:'org.apache.httpcomponents',name:'httpclient',version:'4.3.6')
     compile(group:'org.apache.httpcomponents',name:'fluent-hc',version:'4.3.6')
     compile(group:'org.apache.httpcomponents',name:'httpclient-cache',version:'4.3.6')
     compile(group:'org.apache.httpcomponents',name:'httpmime',version:'4.3.6')

    .
    .

    }
```

Comment: Hi abinandan,Thanks for reply. I have added these settings in both config and buildconfig but plugin still not installed

What i have to do install twilio plugin

Can you please let me know whole process to make it work twilio plugin?

I am beginner in this

Comment: @GregOday what error you are getting?Can you add more details about the probelm you are facing?